# Add an overlay with some information on a video in Windows 8.1

Tags: video, overlay, windows-8.1, mediaelement

I'm currently learning the Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 development in C#. I'm trying to add an overlay on a video playing with MediaElement on Windows 8.1, and I don't find a solution even on Google.

Someone have an idea on how to achieve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Grid Panel to arrange the Overlay Item and MediaElement in your Page.  For more information you can check here, [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207042(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_PanelControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207042%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_PanelControls)

Answer (score 0):

well, here is a guide on how to overlay video to video, and photo to video overlay on Windows 8.1
http://www.goprovideoeditor.com/overlay-video-to-video-windows8-1/

Comment: this is not an answer to the question. OP wanted help with C# related libraries or functions - not ready-to-go solution.